# Bind RadComboBox to ObjectDataSource using DataSet

Tags: asp.net, telerik, radcombobox

I'm trying to bind a RadComboBox to an ObjectDataSource whose select method returns a DataSet object.  I get an error: "'FieldName', is neither a DataColumn nor a DataRelation for table Table".  Just to be sure I'm not crazy, I tried the same with a DropDownList which worked perfectly.  I found in [Telerik's docs](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/panelbar-data-object-data-sources.html) that they support using an ObjectDataSource that returns IEnumerable objects.  So, am I correct that the RadControls don't support using ObjectDataSource when it is using a DataSet?  Really?

Comment: Is it a strongly-typed DataSet?

Answer (score 3):

The link you provided points to a different control. See [here](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/combobox-data-binding-datatable-set-view.html) for the combobox, which is the control in your question title.

The combobox control easily accepts datatable objects from datasets as a source of what to display in the combobox.

[image]

Then the combobox control:

[image]

Select the GetData method (the only option) and then configure your combobox:

[image]

Run:

[image]

**EDIT:**

There seems to be no reason to use a ObjectDataSource if you are already using a dataset and SqlDataAdapter :

```
    DataSet myDataset = new DataSet();

    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=J-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=SO;Integrated Security=True");

    SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(@"SELECT TOP (25) Leg_FirstName FROM GRS_Legislator ORDER BY Leg_FirstName", con);

    adapter.Fill(myDataset);

    RadComboBox1.DataTextField = "Leg_FirstName";
    RadComboBox1.DataValueField = "Leg_FirstName";
    RadComboBox1.DataSource = myDataset;
    RadComboBox1.DataBind();
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response.  I haven't used the approach you describe, but ultimately it seems we're both supplying a DataSet object to the combobox via an ObjectDataSource.  Mine comes from a custom Data Access Layer, and I don't understand why that should give an error.  Am I missing something?

Comment: I guess it depends on how you are setting up the combobox in respsect to the data it shows. If you are doing it via code you will have to make sure you specify a few more variables to make the combobox show what you want it to show.

Comment: Can you point me to what those variables might be?  I assumed that I could point the combobox to the dataset and then tell it the names of the fields in the table to use for value and text.  Is there a step I'm missing?

Comment: Quick question, on your dataset do you only have a dataset, or is it a tableadapter like the one that resembles my first SS in my answer?

Comment: I use a SqlDataAdapter to fill a DataSet which gets returned to the ObjectDataSource

Comment: Understand your point about setting properties in code.  I was trying to find something more elegant.  Thanks for sticking with me.